# jquery toggle and fade in one function?

Tags: jquery, toggle

I was wondering if toggle() and fadeIn() could be used in one function...

i got this to work, but it only fades in after the second click... not on first click of the toggle.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

 $('#business-blue').hide();

  $('a#biz-blue').click(function() {
    $('#business-blue').toggle().fadeIn('slow');
    return false;
  });

// hides the slickbox on clicking the noted link 

  $('a#biz-blue-hide').click(function() { 
     $('#business-blue').hide('fast'); 
     return false; 
  }); 


});



  <a href="#" id="biz-blue">Learn More</a>
        <div id="business-blue" style="border:1px soild #00ff00; background:#c6c1b8; height:600px; width:600px; margin:0 auto; position:relative;">
            <p>stuff here</p>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 22):

Since jQuery 1.4.4 there is a new function for this called `.fadeToggle()`

[Jquery  fadeToggle](http://api.jquery.com/fadeToggle/)

Answer (score 13):

You can use toggle() to alternate between a set of functions. So if you want an element to fadeIn and fadeOut every other click, have a toggle control 2 functions: the fadeIn and the fadeOut. Like this:

```
$('a#biz-blue').toggle(function() {
    $('#business-blue').fadeIn('slow');
    return false;
  },
function() {
    $('#business-blue').fadeOut('slow');
    return false;
  });
```

Comment: Note that this method signature has been removed from jQuery as of 1.9: http://jquery.com/upgrade-guide/1.9/#toggle-function-function-removed

Answer (score 4):

Your question confuses me a bit, because `.toggle()` is basically a show/hide toggle, but you have fadeIn.  The closest guess I have is that you want a fade-toggle, in which case you can do this using [`animate()`](http://api.jquery.com/animate/):

```
$('#business-blue').animate({opacity: 'toggle'}, 800);
```

Another option you may want is the slide up and down using [`.slideToggle()`](http://api.jquery.com/slideToggle/) like this:

```
$('#business-blue').slideToggle('slow');
```

Answer (score 1):

Much better to write a custom function at the bottom of jquery.js:

```
jQuery.fn.fadeToggle = function(speed, easing, callback) {
   return this.animate({opacity: 'toggle'}, speed, easing, callback);
};
```

Then you can call it like this:

```
$('#hiddenElement').fadeToggle('fast');
```

Answer (score 0):

It also looks like someone wrote a [plugin for this](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/togglefade) two years ago.

Answer (score 0):

Very simple

```
$("a#biz-blue").live('click',function(){
   $('#business-blue').slideToggle(200);
});
```

Comment: He asked for fadeIn() specifically; slideToggle() is what it does already.